# Docker-compose: get pulled & deployed images

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, groovy, docker-compose

**Context:**

I am currently trying to create a Jenkins job that builds periodically and updates the images that are in my docker-compose file. I managed to get a basic version of this to work by labeling my services in my `docker-compose.yml`. For example:

```
gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  container_name: 'gitlab'
  labels: 
    update: 'notify'
  ...    

letsencrypt:
  image: 'jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion'
  container_name: 'letsencrypt-companion'
  labels: 
    update: 'auto'
  ...
```

`Notify` meant that it should pull new docker images periodically and notify me that an image is ready to be updated. `Auto` means that it is allowed to automatically deploy the new image.

**Problem:**

I want to make it so that when new images are pulled Jenkins will automatically notify my that new images are ready / deployed. The problem however is that I have to interpret the output of `docker-compose pull` and `docker-compose up -d` to know which images were actually new and deployed. I need a solution that works for a Jenkins pipeline (declarative or scripted)

Answer (score 0):

try to watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZL3hMP9BdmQ; I think that's you are looking for.



 https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower

"If you mount the config file as described below, be sure to also prepend the url for the registry when starting up your watched image (you can omit the https://). Here is a complete docker-compose.yml file that starts up a docker container from a private repo at dockerhub and monitors it with watchtower. Note the command argument changing the interval to 30s rather than the default 5 minutes."

```
version: "3"
services:
  cavo:
    image: index.docker.io/<org>/<image>:<tag>
    ports:
      - "443:3443"
      - "80:3080"
  watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /root/.docker/config.json:/config.json
    command: --interval 30
```